# How to fix font size in alacritty?

Tags: linux, alacritty

My [alacritty](https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty) config file is in `~/.config/alacritty/alacritty.yml` with the following font settings:

```
# Font configuration
font:
  
  [...]

  # Point size
  size: 10.0
```

All other font configuration options are commented out. I verified that [alacritty](https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty) is indeed reading this config file using the `-vvv` flag.

However, whenever I open a new terminal window the font seems to be selected at random. Below a picture of two windows opened one right after the other.

[image]

Comment: Hello, I know I'm a bit late, but did you manage to solve this? I have the same issue

Comment: @enekovalero Kind of. I added an answer below.

Comment: Not a programming question - this belongs over at [unix.se] or [su].

Answer (score 15):

This problem is now reported as [an issue](https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty/issues/5449) at the `alacritty` repository. In general `alacritty` seems to have [many issues with font sizes](https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+font) across different systems.

However, in trying to identify the cause I found that with the `-vv` flag alacritty always starts the terminal with a font size [exactly the double of that in the config file](https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty/issues/5449#issuecomment-907010792).

So for now it is possible to work around this issue by setting up the font size at half of the desired in the config file. For instance, to obtain a font size of 14:

```
# Font configuration
font:
  
  [...]

  # Point size
  size: 7.0
```

And then start `alacritty` with the `-vv` flag:

```
$ alacritty -vv
```

Comment: This workaround does not function on Ubuntu 22.04 with alacritty 0.10.1. Will update this answer if some other workaround comes by.

Comment: I am running `alacritty 0.10.1 (2844606)` on MacOS and do not have a problem adjusting the font size in the yml config... no `-vv` required...

Answer (score 8):

Possible workaround is to use `-o` flag when running alacritty and set `font.size` to desired value. Can be done through .bash_aliases or your WM config to make it faster to use.

Example:

```
alacritty -o font.size=8
```

Btw. I couldn't reproduce random font selection but I had problem with setting custom font size through alacritty config file.

Comment: This worked for me. A terminal emulator in 2022 without a clean instruction to set font size, cool.

Comment: If you issue that command with the `-vv` flag in addition you can see in the debug output that alacritty is nor selecting that font size but something else. However, your suggestion is actually useful to i3 users like myself.

Answer (score 1):

The problem, in my case, was related to tabulation in the font part of the alacritty.yml. The "Size" parameter should be on the same level as each font type definition.
The first screenshot is incorrect, while the second one is correct.

[Incorrect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kubba.png)

[Correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrX2D.png)

If you're having trouble understanding what I mean, take a look at the bottom of the screenshot.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).